# Frozen exe crashes in System Center Configuration Manager 2007

Tags: python, sccm

We are using SCCM 2007 to deploy a custom script (written in Python) which upgrades some software and performs additional configuration on client machines. The script is frozen into an exe using cx_freeze. The frozen exe runs fine from a regular command prompt, but when pushed out through SCCM, it crashes immediately. The system event log shows the error to be "faulting module python27.dll, ... fault address 0x0011570b". The client machine is Win XP Pro 32-bit. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the usual caveat on Windows XP; get off there, get off there very quickly! More importantly though your issue requires some further testing but I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Check user context you are running under
2. ensure it's deploying locally not running from DP
3. could you confirm the system you are testing on doesn't already have python 2.7 installed and may be masking any issues with cx_freeze

Cheers.